# IOS Paypal integration

Tags: paypal, sdk, ios6, in-app-purchase

My Ios app has a purchasing flow. I want to use Paypal as the payment gateway. since they provide an SDK for IOS, is it compulsory to develop the app through In-app purchase? If I use the Paypal SDK directly, will the app get rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you're selling. You have to use In-App Purchase if your app sells digital (non-physical) goods.

More info about In-App Purchase [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf).

You'll find general guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (see section 11 Purchasing and currencies).

Comment: It's physical goods. T-shirts. So does it mean that I can use the Paypal SDK directly & the app wont get rejected?

Comment: Yes, but read through the guidelines to make sure you're not violating any other clause.